# Implicit differentiation in an initial value problem $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, initial-value-problems

In the initial value problem $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$, I want to get a second derivative of $f$ with respect to $t$.
\begin{align*}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(t,y)&=\frac{d}{dt}(f_t+f_yf)\\
&=f_{tt}+f_{ty}f+(f_t+f_yf)f_y+f(f_{yt}+f_{yy}f)\\
&=f_{tt}+2ff_{ty}+f^2f_{yy}+y''f_y.\end{align*}

Is this formula correct?
Of course, I'm assuming that $f$ is smooth enough so that interchange of variables in differentiation is possible.

Comment: It does not seem right... According to your initial formula, shouldn't you have
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (f_t + f_y f) = (f_t+f_y f)_t + (f_t + f_y f)_y (f_t + f_y f) ?$$

If this is the case, I think you are missing some terms.